# Building Eclipse Project With Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

Im following a RESTful web services tutorial from http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-rest-web-service-json-example-tomcat. Is has spring framework dependencies. Instead of downloading the binaries and putting it in the `lib` dir i have included a dependency in `pom.xml` like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.concretepage</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring4</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>   

</project>
```

when i right click on `pom.xml` - `Run>Maven build` it gives me the following error in the console

[image]

> [ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify
>   a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format :
>   or :[:]:.
>   Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
>   generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>   process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
>   process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
>   test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
>   pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
>   install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site,
>   post-site, site-deploy.

I have no prior experience of build mechanisms of java(ant,maven,gradle etc) please guide me how can i successfully create a `war` file from the abv mentioned tut.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you need to create a build configuration for the project first before you can simply select `Run>Maven build`. Creating a build configuration basically means defining what maven goals should be executed during a build.

To do this you need to do the following:

- select `Run>Maven build...`
- in the window that appears give the build configuration a name and then define which goals should be run (fairly standard goals are `clean install` - as shown)
  [image]
- click on `Apply` and then `Run` - this will then close the window and run the build

Now in the future when clicking on `Run>Maven build` this configuration will be selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your project-name. Set the "packaging" to "war"; the packaging by default is "jar". (the group-id is by default your parent's, and so does the version)

```
<artifactId>your.project.name</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

When you try to build it using Maven outside Eclipse - does it work? (from command line, **mvn clean install**...)

BTW what version of eclipse are you using? in Kepler i cannot see the option of Run>build with maven.
[image]

Try to go to "preferences" screen, and see the Maven's configurations:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your time i have edited my question to include the complete `pom.xml` plz have a look

Comment: sry update my question again with a screen shot, right click on pom.xml then choose maven build